# Search strings in a multi-line string with regex and Java

Tags: java, regex

I am quite disturbed by Java syntax for regex... Here is my (multi-line) string:

```
2054:(0020,0032) DS #36 [-249.28170196281\-249.28170196281\0] Image Position (
2098:(0020,0037) DS #12 [1\0\0\0\1\0] Image Orientation (Patient)
2118:(0020,0052) UI #52 [1.3.12.2.11...5.2.30.25....2.20....0.0.0]
2178:(0020,1040) LO #0 [] Position Reference Indicator
2222:(0028,0004) CS #12 [MONOCHROME2] Photometric Interpretation
2242:(0028,0010) US #2 [256] Rows
2252:(0028,0011) US #2 [256] Columns
2262:(0028,0030) DS #18 [1.953125\1.953125] Pixel Spacing
2288:(0028,0100) US #2 [16] Bits Allocated
2298:(0028,0101) US #2 [12] Bits Stored
2352:(0028,1055) LO #6 [Algo1] Window Center & Width Explanation
```

I need `1.953125` and `1.953125` from `DS #18 [1.953125\1.953125] Pixel Spacing`

I tried this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("DS #18 \\[([0-9\\.]*)\\\\([0-9\\.]*)\\] Pixel Spacing"); // os is my string above
System.out.println(m.matches()); // false =(
```

but without success. Any idea? "Pattern.MULTILINE" do not change anything.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are trying to extract multiple occurrences from your input string, you can't use the matches() method, as it will try to match the whole input. So for multiple occurrences:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("DS \\#18 \\[([0-9\\.]*)\\\\([0-9\\.]*)\\] Pixel Spacing",
                            Pattern.MULTILINE|Pattern.DOTALL); 
Matcher m = p.matcher( input );
while( m.find() ) {
    System.out.println("[ "+m.group( 1 )+", "+m.group( 2 )+" ]");
}
```

If you want a single occurrence, then you need to add .* at the beginning and end of your pattern instead:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*DS \\#18 \\[([0-9\\.]*)\\\\([0-9\\.]*)\\] Pixel Spacing.*",
                            Pattern.MULTILINE|Pattern.DOTALL); 
System.out.println(m.matches());
```

Edson

Comment: FYI, the MULTILINE and DOTALL modifiers are unnecessary.  MULTILINE alters the meaning of the anchors (`^` and `$`), and DOTALL alters the meaning of the dot (`.`).  Since you aren't using the dot as a metacharacter, and you're not using the anchors at all, neither of those modifiers is relevant.

Comment: Yes, only the second example requires the DOTALL. I just usually use both by default when doing multiline matches so that I don't need to worry about adding/removing the options when I change my pattern, but you are right.